# What is the random effects structure for an lmer model in R with 1 observation per cell

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme

I am running a regression model where participants rate how they feel at 2 timepoints. Each participant rates how they feel at time 1 and time 2 (within subjects design)

The following model returned an error (see error below):
`lmer(feeling ~ timepoint + (1 + timepoint|sub_id), data = d)`

Error: number of observations (=250) <= number of random effects (=278) for term (1 + timepoint | sub_id); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable.

I found this paper: "Random effects structure for confirmatory hypothesis testing: Keep it maximal" by Dale J. Barr a,⇑, Roger Levy b, Christoph Scheepers a, Harry J. Tily c

The paper states that: "If a factor is within-unit and there are multiple observations per treatment level per unit, then you need a by-unit random slope for that factor. The only exception to this rule is when you only have a single observation for every treatment level of every unit; in this case, the random slope variance would be completely confounded with trial-level error. It follows that a model with a random slope would be unidentifiable, and so a random intercept would be sufficient to meet the conditional independence assumption."

This leads me to believe I can run a model with only the random intercept like so?

`lmer(feeling ~ timepoint + (1|sub_id), data`

The issue is when I try this model, the resulting effect is positive even though the means specify a negative relationship.

When I run this model where I remove the random intercept but keep the random slope, I get a singularity issue but the effect remains negative.

boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

`lmer(feeling ~ timepoint + (0 + timepoint|sub_id), data = d)`

I'm pretty confused about what the best practices are in this scenario.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "positive" and "negative" effect? And do you have a particular reason to model "timepoint" as continuous and not just compare different timepoint means? Not saying it's wrong, but with only 2 points it would seem more intuitive to use the latter approach. In any case, it is very typical that with only 2 observations per cluster you can't model a random slope - you likely won't be able to do that. Also, if you are mainly interested in change in feeling between time 1 and time 2, maybe a latent difference score model would work better.

Comment: To add: sorry, I don't know why I assumed "timepoint" is continuous in your model. Please ignore that part.